# How can I get my doubles to display the decimals with which they are stored?

Tags: c#, double, decimal, itext7

I have a class:

```
public class PairODocs
{
    public string Whirred;
    public int Doc1Count = 0;
    public double Doc1Prcntg = 0.0;
    public int Doc2Count = 0;
    public double Doc2Prcntg = 0.0;
}
```

...that I populate like so:

```
PairODocs pod;
List<String> slDistinctUncommonWords = new List<string>();
lstPairODocs = new List<PairODocs>();
int doc1Count = 0;
int doc2Count = 0;
double doc1Prcntg = 0.0;
double doc2Prcntg = 0.0;
try
{
    slDistinctUncommonWords = GetDistinctWordsFromDB();
    foreach (string whirred in slDistinctUncommonWords)
    {
        pod = new PairODocs();
        doc1Count = GetDoc1CountFor(whirred);
        doc2Count = GetDoc2CountFor(whirred);
        doc1Prcntg = (double)doc1Count / iTotalCountOfWordsInDoc1;
        doc2Prcntg = (double)doc2Count / iTotalCountOfWordsInDoc2; // * 100);
        pod.Whirred = whirred;
        pod.Doc1Count = doc1Count;
        pod.Doc1Prcntg = Math.Round(doc1Prcntg, 7); 
        pod.Doc2Count = doc2Count;
        pod.Doc2Prcntg = Math.Round(doc2Prcntg, 7); 
        lstPairODocs.Add(pod);
    }
}
```

...and then write to a PDF file using iText 7 like so:

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).NumberFormat;
foreach (PairODocs pod in lstPairODocs.OrderByDescending(a => a.Doc1Prcntg).ThenByDescending(a => a.Doc2Prcntg))
{
    if ((pod.Doc1Count > 0) && (pod.Doc2Count > 0))
    {
        Cell cell = new Cell();
        cell.Add(new Paragraph(pod.Whirred));
        cell.SetBackgroundColor(wordmatchHighlight); 
        table.AddCell(cell);

        cell = new Cell();
        cell.Add(new Paragraph(pod.Doc1Count.ToString()));
        cell.SetBackgroundColor(wordmatchHighlight);
        table.AddCell(cell);

        cell = new Cell();
        cell.Add(new Paragraph(pod.Doc1Prcntg.ToString("P", nfi)));
        cell.SetBackgroundColor(wordmatchHighlight);
        table.AddCell(cell);

        cell = new Cell();
        cell.Add(new Paragraph(pod.Doc2Count.ToString()));
        cell.SetBackgroundColor(wordmatchHighlight);
        table.AddCell(cell);

        cell = new Cell();
        cell.Add(new Paragraph(pod.Doc2Prcntg.ToString("P", nfi)));
        cell.SetBackgroundColor(wordmatchHighlight);
        table.AddCell(cell);
}
```

...but instead of showing the values out to 7 decimal places, it only displays two, like so:

[image]

Since there is a Count (1), I don't want Percentage to be 0.00, but 0.00001 or however many decimal points it takes being displayed to show that 1 is not zilch.

Why is the display being restricted to 2 decimal places? And more importantly, how can I fix it so that it will expand out to more? I don't want any value in the "Count" column to display 0.00 in the percentage column unless the corresponding Count is 0.

Comment: Please share a [mcve] so we can _see_ the numbers involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is the display being restricted to 2 decimal places?

By default the percent format specifier `P` is a percent to two decimal places. Use `ToString("P7")` if you want 7 decimal places.

> And more importantly, how can I fix it so that it will expand out to more?

I didn't quite get what you meant by "fix it so it expands to more" - do you want it fixed or variable? You might have to use something like `"0.0000000########%"` for "at least 7 but up to 15 dp" (if that's what you meant by fixed/expanding)

Comment: Nice answer ! Well explained !

Answer (score 1):

You can use this instead of `.ToString()` :

```
cell.Add(new Paragraph(string.Format("{0:N7}%",pod.Doc1Prcntg)));
```